# New session storing the old session information

Tags: spring, spring-security

After filling the form, if the session expired in middle, if I clicked on submit, my page redirected to login, after entering the credentials, the data is automatically saved in database, how can I prevent this.

I used spring security management. I am facing this problem in different pages. Can I make the change in spring security file to avoid this

Can any one help me.

Thanks in advance....

public class AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

```
@Resource(name = "sessionRegistry")
private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;

   String redirectUrl = request.getParameter("spring-security-redirect");

   if(StringUtils.isEmpty(redirectUrl)){
       redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/home");
   }else{
       redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, redirectUrl);      
   }
```

}

Value of spring-security-redirect is request.getHeader("referer")

Comment: Welcome to SO, Can you add a code example?

Answer (score 0):

you could register your implementation of accessDeniedHandler
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/AccessDeniedHandler.html

so it send redirect to url specified in referer. Are you sure your code is invoked? Seems that spring uses savedRequest here, not your url from referer.